# Google Chrome extension using server side rendering

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-extension, server-side-rendering

I am trying to build a chrome extension where the HTML content will be rendered via server in the chrome extension.

using Reactjs / Nextjs stack, and flask server.

The reason behind server-side rendering is basically we don't want to make an extension release every time there is a small change.

Is it feasible? If yes, how should we proceed?

Currently, we have the flask jinja templating and inside of which we inject the build files of reactjs,

In the chrome extension, I am able to render the HTML from the backend, but the react build files i.e, the js files are not rendering the extension.

Answer (score 1):

I would imagine you can do this via building a chrome extension that just contains an iframe pointing to the app.
I'd be curious if the chrome team would actually approve such an extension though.

Answer (score 0):

You can load html and css from remote server, but as you mention, Chrome won't let you run scripts non bundled with the extension. There are couple workarounds, depending on your goals.

1. If it's possible, you could just serve static html and css (so no JS) from your sever. Extension then will load them and display where needed. This isn't really compatible with React as it tightly couples html and js, but for static content (e.g. catalog of articles or latest news in the extension) this might work.
2. As sumG mentioned, you could show your app in iframe inside the extension. In this case you can change not only html and css, but also js code. Significant downside of this approach is that your app won't have access to any of browser APIs (`chrome.history`, `chrome.tabs`, and friends). You can workaround this by implementing kind-of RPC for browser APIs which will sit in the extension and listen for messages in [`onmessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/message_event) and execute commands from received messages. Your script (in React app) then can use [`window.postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) to send messages to browser extension script and use browser APIs. This approach is somewhat limited (e.g. you can't pass functions using messaging API). But most importantly, Google most likely won't like that and will remove your extension from store for doing this. However, if you make your browser part quite restrictive (i.e. exposing only small subset of non-critical APIs) and prove to reviewer that you're using it responsibly, I think there are chances to get away with it.